# HTML table with alignment problems

Tags: html, css

I have these two tables in the `blog_Sec` div of my website's footer, which has 2 alignment problems:

**1)** The tables have headings, and these headings are not in center relative to the table. They appear slightly to the right.

**2)** The tables themselves are not in the center. They are left aligned currently. I want them to be center aligned within `blog_Sec` div.

**JSFiddle code:** http://jsfiddle.net/ahmadka/ukcS8/

**JSFiddle full page preview:** http://jsfiddle.net/ahmadka/ukcS8/show/

Using `display: table-row`, I can solve the first problem, but then it removes the spacing between the heading and the table which doesn't look nice. So not really usable.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

http://jsfiddle.net/ukcS8/11/

isseu#2  add

```
table align="center"
```

Comment: heading has to be in the center, relative to its corresponding table, not on left ..

Comment: also, the table appears right aligned now .. (ignore the headings, and see the the right edges of both tables line up)

Comment: In `http://jsfiddle.net/ukcS8/3/show/`, you've just shifted the table below to right completely .. it needs to be center aligned .. also, headings are where they were originally, so no change in them (compare with the original here: `http://jsfiddle.net/ukcS8/show/`)

Comment: Your `http://jsfiddle.net/ukcS8/3/` and `http://jsfiddle.net/ukcS8/4/` are visually exactly the same ..

Comment: Payment Partners or Shipping Partners you write only <table> please write down <table align="center"> both of tables

Comment: Marked your answer as acceptable because of your effort, although I kind of re-wrote the code myself from scratch ..  Thanks for trying though :)

Answer (score 0):

you should use this css code.

```
.yourdiv {
    left: 50%;
    right: 50%;
    }
```